# Whether in C, a called function automatically returns value returned by its called function if not written explicitly?

Tags: c, function, return

I have a code as following. And the function slogan always returns the value returned by `printf` i.e number of characters being printed. Whether it is defined as per C compiler? What is the implicit concept of complete mechanism of returning?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int slogan( ) ;
  int c = 5 ;
  c = slogan( ) ;
  printf ( "\n%d", c ) ;
}

int slogan( )
{
  printf ( "\nOnly He men use C!" ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) to use the return value when you drop off a the end of a value returning function, you can not rely on this behavior.

This is covered in the draft C99 standard section `6.9.1` *Function definitions* paragraph *12* which says:

> If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by
>   the caller, the behavior is undefined.

It is the same section and paragraph in the draft C11 standard.

In your case it works only by luck, possibly the return value is being returned in a register that is not overwritten when you return. For [System V calling convention](http://wiki.osdev.org/Calling_Conventions#Cheat_Sheets) will return a small enough parameter in `eax/rax` and if we look at a slight modified test program [live on Coliru using gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0360b91e2651d0c) with the `-fverbose-asm` flag:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int slogan( ) ;
  int c = 5, d ;
  c = slogan( ) ;
  d = printf ( "\n%d", c ) ;
  printf ( "\n%d", d ) ;
}

int slogan( )
{
  printf ( "\nOnly He men use C!" ) ;
}
```

We can see from the assembly that `c` and `d` obtain their value from `eax`:

```
movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)  # tmp61, c
movl    -4(%rbp), %eax  # c, tmp62
movl    %eax, %esi      # tmp62,
movl    $.LC0, %edi
movl    $0, %eax
call    printf  
movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)  # tmp63, d
movl    -8(%rbp), %eax  # d, tmp64
movl    %eax, %esi      # tmp64,
movl    $.LC0, %edi 
movl    $0, %eax
call    printf
```

Comment: "return value is being returned in a register that is not overwritten when you return"

that seems the answer as it happens even if I make one more call!! main->A->B->C... with A and having nothing to return.